# Can't import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I just started learning Spring and I have problem importing Classes from Spring, please help! I tried almost everything what I found as a solutions, but it was a failure...

> Error:
>
> The import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext cannot be
>   resolved.

Here's my code

```
import org.springframework.context.*; //I can import this
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext; //But I can't import this
```

or

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.*; //I can import this
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; //But I can't import this
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <groupId>helloworld</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <version>1.0</version>



  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: put some code would be helpful

Comment: What code could I put? I think that this is enough for my problem. I cannot import classes from spring framework library. That's my whole pom.xml, I don't think that my main class body has to do something with the error because it's empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ApplicationContext](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.java.) resides in that package.

In your IDE if you control click on the import statement it should show you which jar it is resolving to. If it isnt run `mvn clean install` which will build and pull dependencies you need

Your project may not be auto importing maven dependencies so it doesn't yet resolve.

Comment: Thank you! I solved it by deleting maven repository and than running `mvn clean install`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do maven clean and mavin install and also check for proper dependency